# Centered text with line numbering

Tags: linum-mode

Writeroom mode and linum mode are incompatible (leave numbers at
far left, making them useless for (evil) jumping).  Is there anything
else I can do to get centered text with (relative) line numbering close to the text?

Comment: How about right-aligning the line-numbers?  `(setq linum-format "%7d")`  There are a few threads that pop-up on Google when searching for this issue, so there are probably other solutions that have already been written up.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but did you try commands such as `center-region`, `center-paragraph`, and `center-line`?

Comment: @Drew, sorry I was unclear.  I don't want to center the text in the file, just on the screen while editing.  It seems a bit wrong, disturbing, to me if I am editing a file with lines spanning only half the screen that they should occupy the left half of the screen while the right is empty.

Comment: I see. I just use separate frames (window-manager windows), and fit the frames to the buffer text. No wasted space at all, and text positioned anywhere I want on the display.

Comment: have you thought about hilighting the line number with something like the `hlinum` package?

Answer (score 1):

[Centered-window-mode](https://github.com/anler/centered-window-mode) works with line numbers, though it doesn't provide the numbers directly next to the the text.

However, if you are using the latest emacs, it now has [native display of line numbers](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2017-06/msg00318.html). If you set `display-line-numbers-type 'relative` or `display-line-numbers-type 'visual` and use in combination with `centered-window-mode` you'll get the numbers right next to the centered text, and with relative line numbers except for current line.

Comment: It does, but the numbers are placed at the far left, making it difficult to see which lines they belong to. It also 'centers' text further to the left than writeroom, for some reason.

Comment: you can modify how it centers with `cwm-centered-window-width`. But I don't know what to say concerning your difficulty with number placing, if just having it on the left isn't going to work.

Comment: I've updated this answer with reference to the new native line numbering.